# How do you iterate through documents in a sub-collection within a transaction for firestore android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to be able to delete all documents within a sub-collection as part of a transaction in android.  I found the following code but this is for Node.js

```
// First perform the query
db.collection('job_skills').where('job_id','==',post.job_id).get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    // Once we get the results, begin a batch
    var batch = db.batch();

    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // For each doc, add a delete operation to the batch
        batch.delete(doc.ref);
    });

    // Commit the batch
    return.batch.commit();
}).then(function() {
  // Delete completed!
  // ...
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: That code doesn't really do a transaction.  It's a batch.  Are you asking how to do a batch delete with the Android SDK?

Comment: I do want to do a transaction.  I need to do updates, sets, and deletes at the same time.  Unfortunately, this was all I could find.

Comment: The documentation for transactions for all supported platforms is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see in your code is not called transaction, it's called a batch. So if you want to delete all the documents within a collection using Android SDK, I recommend you use the following methods:

```
private void deleteCollection(final CollectionReference collection, Executor executor) {
    Tasks.call(executor, new Callable<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            int batchSize = 10;
            Query query = db.collection("job_skills").whereEqualTo("job_id", job_id);
            List<DocumentSnapshot> deleted = deleteQueryBatch(query);

            while (deleted.size() >= batchSize) {
                DocumentSnapshot last = deleted.get(deleted.size() - 1);
                query = collection.orderBy(FieldPath.documentId()).startAfter(last.getId()).limit(batchSize);

                deleted = deleteQueryBatch(query);
            }

            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the `deleteQueryBatch()` method:

```
@WorkerThread
private List<DocumentSnapshot> deleteQueryBatch(final Query query) throws Exception {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = Tasks.await(query.get());

    WriteBatch batch = query.getFirestore().batch();
    for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : querySnapshot) {
        batch.delete(snapshot.getReference());
    }
    Tasks.await(batch.commit());

    return querySnapshot.getDocuments();
}
```

Even if the delete operation is not recomended by Firebase team because it has negative security and performance implications, you can still use it for small data sets.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Much appreciated.  But is there a way to get this to work within a transaction?

Comment: I understand the example I posted above is for a batch, but it was the only thing I could find (sorry for any confusion).  I need to be able to do this in a transaction.

Comment: [Firestore transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) are useful when you want to update a field's value based on its current value, or the value of some other field. You could increment a counter by creating a transaction that reads the current value of the counter, increments it, and writes the new value to Cloud Firestore. What you can see in this batch are called atomic operations, either all of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied. There is no need to use transactions in this case. These 2 methods will help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Okay.  I'll give that a shot.  Thanks Alex!  I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: Okay one more wrinkle.  I need to do a couple of updates and delete a collection within the same batch.   What is the easiest way to accomplish this while still breaking up the delete into a small batch size?

Comment: You can just add other update operations to be apart of the same batch. Please see also the [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes). See the example in code.

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm aware of the functionality of batching with combining deletes with writes and sets.  To clear up some confusion to my last comment, I was referring to adding writes to your delete/batch solution.  I'm aware that it is encouraged to delete in small batches.  Do you have a solution to be able to batch the deletes like above but include writes within that solution?

Comment: I haven't created a method also for write operation because the problem is when deleting but you can adapt it also for write / update operations. Should be even simpler.